# Updating label values using after() method .

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a page in which  has ten labels and then update the values  using the after() method .But the screen hangs .
The start definition is bind to a button  creates the labels , and then using after method i am trying to call the update method in recursive fashion to update the label values .
Is their another way to call the update() method from the main function (**main**) .

```
 def update(self,i):



        self.lab_hold_X=25

        self.data_hold_mL_screen[i].place(x=self.lab_hold_X,y=self.y_place)
        self.data_hold_mL_screen[i]['text']=str(int(self.data_hold_mL_screen[i]['text']) + 1)

        self.y_place +=30
        self.valuess=i+1

        if self.valuess <=10:
            self.after(1000,self.update(self.valuess))
        else :
            self.valuess=0
            self.after(1000,self.update(self.valuess))
    def start(self):
        self.lab_hold_X=25
        self.lab_hold_Y=10


        for i in range(0,10):
            self.lab_hold_Y +=30
            self.data_hold_mL_screen[i].place(x=self.lab_hold_X,y=self.lab_hold_Y)  
            self.lab_hold_X =25

            self.after(1000,update(0))
```

I basically wish to create a page wherein i can get values from any external device and then display it on the screen , screen shows 10 values , on 11th iteration   a value is recieved the screen shifts upward and the 1st value is  discarded and the second value is displayed in 1st label position ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example using a list to hold the last 10 values, and a second list to hold the Label's StringVars that are updated.  And please do not use "i", "l", or "O" as single character variable names as they can look like numbers.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class LabelTest():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.string_vars=[]  ## contains pointers to the label vars
        self.values=[]
        self.start()
        Button(self.master, text="Quit", bg="orange", width=15,
               command=self.master.quit).grid(row=20)
        self.update(1)

    def update(self, ctr):
        """ Change the StringVars to the new values
        """
        if len(self.values) > 9:
            ## full so delete the first one
            del self.values[0]
        self.values.append(ctr)
        ## update the StringVar with the corresponding
        ## value from self.values
        for offset in range(len(self.values)):
            self.string_vars[offset].set(self.values[offset])

        ctr += 1

        if ctr < 20:  ## let's put a limit on this
            self.master.after(1000, partial(self.update, ctr))

    def start(self):
        """ create 10 labels with StringVars that can be changed
            each time a new value is created
        """
        for ctr in range(10):
            var=StringVar()
            lab=Label(self.master, textvariable=var).grid(row=ctr)
            self.string_vars.append(var) ## the variables to be updated
            ## initial variable value
            self.values.append("***")  ## the values

master=Tk()
LabelTest(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: the code works great but i do not understand how the label var is updated by self.string_vars . I m confused bcz till now i used the lab.config() to update the labels , or delete and insert methods todo the same .

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
self.after(1000,update(0))
```

... needs to be this:

```
self.after(1000,lambda: update(0))
```

The same is true for the other places you call `after`. `after` requires a *reference* to a function, but you are *calling* the function and passing the result of the function to `after`. And since your function returns nothing, nothing is getting executed after 1000 ms.